# CSS sliding underline on hover - color transition does not work on a visited link

Tags: css, sliding, visited

I created a navigation that underlines the links on hover (sliding underline starting from the middle going outward) and also transforms the link from a dark green to a lighter green. This works totally fine except when one of the links has been clicked on and it becomes a "visited" link: when I re-click a visited link the sliding underline still works but the color will not transform from dark to light green, it just stays as dark green. I've tried everything I can think of but can't get a visited link to transform it's color like a non-visited link.

HTML:

```
<div id="topNavigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="encyclopedia.html">ENCYCLOPEDIA</a></li>
        <li><a href="journal.html">JOURNAL</a></li>
        <li><a href="society.html">SOCIETY</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topNavigation a:link {
    font-family:"Quicksand-Regular", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    position:relative;
    color:#00590d;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:color .35s;
    -webkit-transition:color .35s;
}

#topNavigation a:hover {
    color:#7ead34;
}

#topNavigation a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #7ead34;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#topNavigation a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

#topNavigation a:visited {
    color:#00590d;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

You can see what I'm talking about here: 
http://www.religionandnature.com/website2015/

The link for the Encyclopedia page is visited and the color doesn't transition. The other links aren't visited and work fine. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: maybe try using RGB instead of hex.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the `:visited` declaration is underneath `:hover`. This means that the `:visited` color will always override the hover color.

[**Use the LVHA order**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) — link, visited, hover, active!

> The :visited CSS pseudo-class lets you select only links that have
>   been visited. This style may be overridden by any other link-related
>   pseudo-classes, that is :link, :hover, and :active, appearing in
>   subsequent rules. **In order to style appropriately links, you need to
>   put the :visited rule after the :link rule but before the other ones,
>   defined in the LVHA-order: :link — :visited — :hover — :active**.

The hover color will now override the visited color.

Like this:

```css
#topNavigation a:link {}
#topNavigation a:visited {}/*Place before :hover*/
#topNavigation a:hover {}
#topNavigation a:before {}
#topNavigation a:hover:before {}
```

Comment: YES!! Thank you so much. The ORDER of CSS will drive me nuts all the time. Works perfectly now.